# Splitting a String using split() not getting required result

Tags: java

I have a String(freeText) `"Manas \"Jaikant IBM\""`. I want to split into two strings:

```
String normalMatch="Manas";
String exactMatch="Jaikant IBM";
```

It means that String normalMatch contains Manas and String exactMatch  contains Jaikant IBM.

i am using the `split()` method of String class in Java

```
String[] splittedText= freeText.split("\\s");
```

I am getting 3 string elements but i need 2 string  elements only.

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695143/split-a-quoted-string-with-a-delimiter).

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring` instead of `split`:

```
int index = freeText.indexOf(" ");
String normalMatch = freeText.substring(0,index);
String exactMatch  = freeText.substring(index); // endIndex == freeText.length())
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on quotes(") then, you will get Manas and Jaikant IBM and can ignore the 3rd value.